# ¿Solo puedo utilizar números para arrojar una lectura en SQLITE desde Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

intentare ser lo más claro posible pero soy bastante novato en programación.

He creado una interfaz gráfica en python que se conecta a una base de datos, y una de las funciones es  leer los datos que están asociados a un ID, en este caso el ID es una matrícula por lo que contiene letras y números.

El problema surge al realizar la búsqueda con

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM RECORDATORIO WHERE MATRICULA="+ matriculaVar.get())`

Si guardo la matricula como números, no hay problema al realizar la búsqueda, editar/actualizar información, sin embargo, si guardo la matrícula con letras y números, aunque esta se guarda en la base de datos con el resto de datos, al realizar la lectura de ella para un futura modificación, me salta el siguiente **error**:

`````
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: asd````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que tu matricula es = `AS45D9090`, entonces tu consulta quedaría como

`"SELECT * FROM RECORDATORIO WHERE MATRICULA="+ matriculaVar.get()`

`SELECT * FROM RECORDATORIO WHERE MATRICULA=AS45D9090`

Para ejecutar una consulta con strings estás deben estar encerradas entre comillas, debería quedar como

`SELECT * FROM RECORDATORIO WHERE MATRICULA='AS45D9090'`

Por lo que tu código podría quedar como

`"SELECT * FROM RECORDATORIO WHERE MATRICULA='"+ matriculaVar.get() + "'"`

para poder generar dicha string.

Hay que tener en cuenta que este método que usas no es muy recomendable dado que es muy propenso a sql injection, por lo cual deberías leer un poco sobre ello y buscar un método más seguro una vez que domines este.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, ese era el fallo.
Tengo en el mismo código un pequeño problema para actualizar la información que seguro es similar, he tratado de arreglarlo del mismo modo:

```cursor.execute("UPDATE RECORDATORIO SET ITV=?, ADR=?, IMDG=?, TACOGRAFO=?, FREE=?, NOTES=? WHERE MATRICULA= ' " + matriculaVar.get() + " ' ",(datosVar))```

como me has indicado antes pero no funciona, podrias echarme un cable? (los espacios entre comillas es para visualizarlo mejor, y tengo datosVar con los datos para evitar la injeccion de sql o como se diga

Comment: Ahí muy probablemente el problema sea en como estés pasando `datosVar`, lo recomendable sería que hicieras otra pregunta para no llenar aquí los comentarios de una pregunta que no va con la original, indicando que tienes en `datosVar` y qué error te da